# choose either element or element type using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two combo boxes, and would like to select either stationType or station (if station is selected set stationType to zero and vice versa). The result of the following code sets both to zero when one of them changed. Is there a way to keep my selection and reset the other box only?

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="options: lookups.stationTypes, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', value: ProductPlanItem().StationTypeId"></select>
```

and

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="options: lookups.stations, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', value: ProductPlanItem().StationId"></select>
```

ProductPlanItem is like this:

```
function ProductPlanItem() {
        var me = this
        me.StationTypeId = ko.observable()
        me.StationId = ko.observable()
        me.StationTypeId.subscribe(function () {
            me.StationId(0)
        })
        me.StationId.subscribe(function () {
            me.StationTypeId(0)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `ko.computed` with a `read` and `write` function for this. The problem with your current set up is that setting `StationId` in the first subscribe triggers the second subscribe.

Here's your basic behavior in an example:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  this.first = ko.observable(1);
  this.second = ko.observable(2);

  this.oddsAndZero = [0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
  this.evensAndZero = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

  this.firstSelection = ko.computed({
    read: this.first,
    write: function(newValue) {
      this.first(newValue);
      this.second(0);
    },
    owner: this
  });
  
  this.secondSelection = ko.computed({
    read: this.second,
    write: function(newValue) {
      this.second(newValue);
      this.first(0);
    },
    owner: this
  });

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<select data-bind="options: oddsAndZero, value: firstSelection"></select>
<select data-bind="options: evensAndZero, value: secondSelection"></select>
```

Comment: Exactly, I forget to use computed